# Symfony2 assetic compass diffrent asset_url paths in prod and dev environments

Tags: symfony, ubuntu, sass, assetic

I try to configure my Symfony2 project with compass and Assetic on Ubuntu 12.04 (give up to run this project with compass and Assetic on Windows XP).

I configured compass and it works fine when I start my project in dev environment, though in prod I have wrong asset_url paths to my css output files from compass filter.

Here is my config.yml assetic section:

```
# Assetic Configuration
assetic:
debug:          %kernel.debug%
use_controller: false
#bundles:        [ ]
#java: /usr/bin/java
filters:
    cssrewrite: ~
    sass: 
      bin: /usr/local/bin/sass
      apply_to: "\.scss$"
      #bin: C:/Ruby200/bin/sass this is for Windows not working though
    compass: 
        images_dir: %kernel.root_dir%/../web/images
        http_path:  /images
        #bin: C:/Ruby200/bin/compass.bat this is for Windows not working though
        bin: /usr/local/bin/compass
    closure:
        jar: %kernel.root_dir%/Resources/java/compiler.jar
    yui_css:
        jar: %kernel.root_dir%/Resources/java/yuicompressor-2.4.7.jar
```

I include assetic filter in **app/Resources/views/base.html.twig**

```
 {% stylesheets filter="compass" "@PortalSlubnyMainBundle/Resources/public/css/settings.scss"%}
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset_url }}" />
 {% endstylesheets %}
 <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="{{ asset('favicon.ico') }}" />
```

When I run my project through app_dev.php I got properly formatted asset_url

which look like this: **/app_dev.php/css/6262784_settings_1.css**

In prod environment I got wrong urls sth like this: **/css/6262784.css** (404 not found error)

I clear the cache for prod and dev and nothing has changed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In dev environment assetic uses by default controller. So your url's for prod and dev environment are good.

To generete asset files you need to run `app/console assetic:dump` and those files will be used in prod environment.

Comment: `app/console assetic:dump --env=prod --no-debug` for production environment ;-)